# Quelles notions sémantiques sous-tendent l'étymologie et les acceptions de « déjà » ?

Tags: étymologie

> [ [Étymologie :](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0#.C3.89tymologie) ] Composé de *dès* et
>   de l’ancien français *jà* (« maintenant ; déjà »), du latin *iam* (« maintenant, dès maintenant, déjà »).
>
> 1. Indique un changement d’état ou une atteinte du critère **jusqu’à présent** ou **jusqu’alors**.
> 2. **Auparavant**.

Il existe un glissement sémantique car l'étymon signifie une période différente des périodes dans acceptions 1 et 2  :

3. *dès* + *jà*  = 'dès maintenant' = le présent + le futur.

Par contre,

dans 1 : 4. **jusqu'à present** =  le passé + le présent ;
5. **jusqu'alors** = n'importe quel moment et temps (le passé, le présent ou futur).

dans 2 : 6. **auparavant** = le passé.

Comment: Il n'y aucun glissement sémantique, tous ces emplois de déjà indique une rupture avant/après un certain point sur la ligne du temps.  Le temps employé (présent/passé) indique la place sur la ligne du temps par rapport au moment T (présent du locuteur).

Answer (score 2):

Le terme latin *iam*<sup>1</sup> qui donne naissance à ce terme n'y est pas très bien glosé. Si on suit le lien vers [l'article](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/iam#la) sur ce mot, on y lit :

> Jadis, un jour, à un moment donné.

C'est en effet un moment du passé, du présent, ou de l'avenir que peut indiquer *iam*. J'imagine que la raison en est que le fond de ce mot est le sens « à *ce* temps [dont je parle] », locution qui désignera un temps non limité par la chronologie. Ce n'est que pour le rendre saillant.

Un autre mot apparenté est « ya » en espagnol, qui montre très facilement cette fonction :

> **Ya** lo había hecho.
>   
> <sub>*Je l'avais **déjà** fait [avant un autre acte].*</sub>
>
> **Ya** ha venido.
>   
> <sub>*Il est **déjà** venu [avant le présent] et il est toujours ici.*</sub>

Et le plus intéressant :

> ¡**Ya** verás!
>   
> <sub>*Tu vas voir [un jour dans l'avenir, ce jour-là] !*</sub>

Comme Laure le dit, lorsqu'on emploie *déjà* le temps indiqué change selon l'énoncé. Et remarquez bien que l'action dans chaque phrase se déroulerait au moment désigné sans ou avec *déjà* (ou *ya*). Cela explique l'élément *jà*, qui ne sert qu'à mettre en avant un certain moment.

Or l'autre élément, *dès*, porte aujourd'hui le même sens qu'autrefois, voir « à partir de ». De plus, selon [l'article anglais](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iam#Usage_notes) sur Wiktionnaire, *iam* pouvait communiquer ce même sens :

> *Iam* means, generally, “at some point previous” or “since some point previous”.
>   
> <sub>*Iam* veut souvent dire « à un certain moment du passé » ou « dès un certain moment du passé ».</sub>

*Dès* servirait donc à résoudre l'ambiguïté entre ces deux sens de *jà* ou à doubler sa signification.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Voir aussi [ce lien](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/jam#Latin) vers *jam*, une forme collatérale de *iam* qui montre plus clairement son origine en *diem* « à (un) jour ». (Les développements phonologiques pour arriver à /jam/ sont très attendus.) Il me semble que le glissement de « jour » en « moment » représente un déplacement intéressant du centre sémantique, même si on remarque que *[dies](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies#la)* avait toute une gamme de significations même en latin, et que les mots comme « jour » sont enclins à s'employer de façon figurée à travers plusieurs langues.</sub>